# Finding the error in an argument

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $z=f(x,y)$ and $y=x^2$, then by the chain rule

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

Therefore

$2x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$

and

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$

What is wrong with this argument?

I have a feeling that

1.) $x$ and $y$ do not have partial derivatives because they are single-variable, and

2.) $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ cannot be zero, because $y=x^2$ and therefore the derivative of any $y$ term exists.

How is my reasoning? I am pretty confused by this question.

Comment: My first question for you is why do you think this line of reasoning is incorrect? Did someone tell you it wasn't right?

Comment: I also will note that if $2x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =0$, then either $x=0$ or $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =0$.

Comment: @BSplitter the problem itself poses this argument as incorrect, the object being to find out why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing wrong. Just change it into

$$\frac{d z}{d x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

Note that that the first term is $\frac{d z}{d x}$, which is different from $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. So they cannot cancel out. The partial derivatives do exist, but be careful not to mix it up with $\frac{d z}{d x}$, which is NOT a partial derivative.

Actually, a better way to say this is that

$$\left[\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right]_{y=x^2}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}.$$

Where I have clearly written down the restriction $y=x^2$.